# breeze-brideg-angular2 : do I need to create my breeze entity classes

Tags: angular, typescript, breeze

do I need to create my breeze entity classes when using the breeze-brideg-angular2 because otherwise how do I get the below line of code working in the suggested solution at https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.bridge.angular2/blob/master/README.md

```
import { Customer } from './entities';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That snippet assumes that you have created classes for your model entities. Such classes aren't required but they sure are helpful.

You can create them by hand and that's not hard.

In many cases you can generate them from server-side #C classes with a tool that I believe is described in the referenced TempHire example (the code is there for sure).

Better documentation would help, we agree.

Comment: Thanks for the response Mr. Bell. But I might as well take this opportunity to as you something related.

Comment: Thanks for the response Mr. Bell. But I might as well take this opportunity to ask you something else but related. I developed couple of big LoB applications using Breeze and Angular1x without needing to do any UoW pattern on the client or server side. Breeze tracks all the changes since my last save and I can reject or commit changes at will. But to get Breeze working with Angular2 and typescript looks quiet daunting. I downloaded the TempHire code but looks Greek and Latin when compared to what I did in Angular1x. Really need something well documented for ng2 and breeze.

Comment: @sskasim The UoW pattern is just one approach to managing datasets/tasks/workflows on the client. At a minimum you should abstract your persistence layer behind some kind of a service that offers a well defined facade to the UI components. The UoW pattern has proven itself over time as a very robust design pattern for medium to large scale applications. It is more than just a facade over the EntityManager.

Comment: Besides holding the data, it is comprised of services that perform operations on the data in accordance with the business logic. This stuff doesn't belong in the UI, Whether you structure this using the UoW pattern or some other services doesn't really matter as long as it's architected to be extensible and can adapt easily to changing business requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I recently struggled with the same question.  I did not use unit of work but rather the single repository - dbContext as shown in John Papa's SPA Pluralsight example for 1.x.  Model project referenced in data project compiled to a data.dll

Try this:

(I did this with an angular-cli generated project)
Take the entire tools folder from the temphire example and drop it into your project folder.  Make sure you have done the npm install for handlebars as suggested in metadatagenerator.exe docs.

copy the package.json scripts: lines for metadata: entities: and metadata-entities:

you will need those, and will have to adjust both the path to your data model and the name of the dll itself.

```
 "metadata": ".\\tools\\bin\\MetadataGenerator.exe..\\CFSWH.Web\\bin\\Debug\\CFSWH.Data.dll -o metadata.json",
"entities": "node ./tools/tsgen.js",
"metadata-entities": "npm run metadata && npm run entities"
```

As you probably know there are a few tricky lines in the dbContext.  My first failures were due to forgetting that and using a typical reverse engineered dbcontext from my SQL database which did not have these lines:

```
public CFS_WHContext() : base(nameOrConnectionString: "CFS_WH") { }

    static CFS_WHContext()
    {
        var type1 = typeof(System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices);
        Database.SetInitializer<CFS_WHContext>(null);
    }
```

In the tools folder, you need to adjust the tsgen.js file

```
tsGen.generate({
    inputFileName: './metadata.json',
    outputFolder: './src/app/core/entities',
    camelCase: true,
    kebabCaseFileNames: true,
    baseClassName: 'EntityBase'
});
```

to reflect the correct output folder for the entities.  You must create this folder in advance.  Copy the entity-base.ts file from the temphire entities folder (or fiddle tsgen-core.js to not use it.  Suggest not doing that as it has extended properties for entityState that I think may come in handy)

Make sure you have the right path to the bin folder holding your dll in the script in package.json.

Assume you have installed all the breeze files install both server and client shown in temphire, including these dependencies in package.json

```
"breeze-bridge-angular2": "^0.3.6",
"breeze-client": "^1.6.0",
```

now go to command prompt and run metadata-entities.  (easier to debug if you npm run them one at a time)

Putting this out quickly so happy to expand on it if anything isn't clear.  Hope Ward or Jay will chime in if I have done or explained something in a particularly boneheaded or misleading fashion.

Would like to see more Breeze fans shared ng2 experiences here until Ward and Jay have time to document more.  Breeze is worth the effort.